# Can't click or tap below the bottom half of a screen on website on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios7, responsive-design, click, viewport

I've been given the task to try and fix an issue on this site:
[redacted]

When you tap below the bottom half of the screen on an iPhone 5, taps aren't registering and so links can't be clicked, etc.

I tried debugging by alerting what element is tapped, and nothing is registering below the halfway point. If you scroll down the page so the link you want to click is above the top half, it works perfectly fine.

I've searched around and there seems to be some issues with iPhone 5 *apps* (as far as I can tell, I'm not an app developer!) but I can't seem to find anyone having the same error on a responsive website.

What's going on - is it something to do with the viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your DOM you have an **`<iframe "id=FirebugUI">`** that sits right below your  element. It has some inline styles that include `visibility:hidden;` and a `z-index` of a super large number which means it's a hidden element that is on top of everything. You have some options:

**1 - Get rid of it** if you're familiar with what firebugUI is and can comfortably remove it all together. then you're good to go. It's probably being injected with some javascript.

**2 - display none** - you can add this css to remove it:

```
#FirebugUI {
display: none !important;
}
```

You'll need to add the important to the value so it overrides the inline styles. This may render the FirebugUI useless though.

**3 - z index** - you can update the z-index by setting it to like 0. But that will probably render this thing useless. so you might as well just remove this plugin if you're going to do that. You'll also need to use the !important value to override the inline styles.

Comment: I totally overlooked that because I thought it was my browser inserting it rather than it being on the page! I suppose I should have tried it anyway. Thank you very much.